# How to just get a the selected output using find() function in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I have executed this code

```
 db.courses.find({isPublished: true , tags: "backend"} , {name: 1 , author:1}).sort({name: 1})
```

in MongoDB shell and it gave me the required output. Now I am trying to execute the same code using mongoose and it gives me this

```
[
  model {
    '$__': InternalCache {
      strictMode: true,
      selected: [Object],
      shardval: undefined,
      saveError: undefined,
      validationError: undefined,
      adhocPaths: undefined,
      removing: undefined,
      inserting: undefined,
      version: undefined,
      getters: {},
      _id: 5a68fde3f09ad7646ddec17e,
      populate: undefined,
      populated: undefined,
      wasPopulated: false,
      scope: undefined,
      activePaths: [StateMachine],
      pathsToScopes: {},
      ownerDocument: undefined,
      fullPath: undefined,
      emitter: [EventEmitter],
      '$options': true
    },
    isNew: false,
    errors: undefined,
    _doc: {
      _id: 5a68fde3f09ad7646ddec17e,
      name: 'ASP.NET MVC Course',
      author: 'Mosh'
    },
    '$init': true
  },
  model {
    '$__': InternalCache {
      strictMode: true,
      selected: [Object],
      shardval: undefined,
      saveError: undefined,
      validationError: undefined,
      adhocPaths: undefined,
      removing: undefined,
      inserting: undefined,
      version: undefined,
      getters: {},
      _id: 5a68fdc3615eda645bc6bdec,
      populate: undefined,
      populated: undefined,
      wasPopulated: false,
      scope: undefined,
      activePaths: [StateMachine],
      pathsToScopes: {},
      ownerDocument: undefined,
      fullPath: undefined,
      emitter: [EventEmitter],
      '$options': true
    },
    isNew: false,
    errors: undefined,
    _doc: {
      _id: 5a68fdc3615eda645bc6bdec,
      name: 'Express.js Course',
      author: 'Mosh'
    },
    '$init': true
  },
  model {
    '$__': InternalCache {
      strictMode: true,
      selected: [Object],
      shardval: undefined,
      saveError: undefined,
      validationError: undefined,
      adhocPaths: undefined,
      removing: undefined,
      inserting: undefined,
      version: undefined,
      getters: {},
      _id: 5a68fdd7bee8ea64649c2777,
      populate: undefined,
      populated: undefined,
      wasPopulated: false,
      scope: undefined,
      activePaths: [StateMachine],
      pathsToScopes: {},
      ownerDocument: undefined,
      fullPath: undefined,
      emitter: [EventEmitter],
      '$options': true
    },
    isNew: false,
    errors: undefined,
    _doc: {
      _id: 5a68fdd7bee8ea64649c2777,
      name: 'Node.js Course',
      author: 'Mosh'
    },
    '$init': true
  },
  model {
    '$__': InternalCache {
      strictMode: true,
      selected: [Object],
      shardval: undefined,
      saveError: undefined,
      validationError: undefined,
      adhocPaths: undefined,
      removing: undefined,
      inserting: undefined,
      version: undefined,
      getters: {},
      _id: 5a68fe2142ae6a6482c4c9cb,
      populate: undefined,
      populated: undefined,
      wasPopulated: false,
      scope: undefined,
      activePaths: [StateMachine],
      pathsToScopes: {},
      ownerDocument: undefined,
      fullPath: undefined,
      emitter: [EventEmitter],
      '$options': true
    },
    isNew: false,
    errors: undefined,
    _doc: {
      _id: 5a68fe2142ae6a6482c4c9cb,
      name: 'Node.js Course by Jack',
      author: 'Jack'
    },
    '$init': true
  }
]
```

Although it gives me the required output along with some extra not understandable things which makes it non-readable.I am actually following a NodeJS course in which the instructer uses Mac and his output is same as the MongoDB output.My code in javascript is

```
 const mongoose = require("mongoose"); 


const fun = async() => {

    await mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/Exercise"); 

    const schema  = mongoose.Schema({
        name: String , 
        author: String , 
        tags: [String] ,
        date: Date , 
        isPublished: Boolean , 
        price: Number 
    }); 

    const Course = mongoose.model("Course" , schema); 

    const result = await Course.find({isPublished: true
        , tags: "backend"})
        .sort({name: 1 })
    .select({name: 1  , author: 1 }); 

    console.log(result); 

}
fun();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert Mongoose model to object.

You can convert to object using lean() function.

```
const result = await Course.find({isPublished: true
        , tags: "backend"})
        .sort({name: 1 })
    .select({name: 1  , author: 1 })
.lean()
```

Also, it can be done by other way as,

```
let result = await Course.find({isPublished: true
        , tags: "backend"})
        .sort({name: 1 })
    .select({name: 1  , author: 1 })
result = result.map(r => r.toObject())
```